# MySQL Union sort works unexpected at different server

Tags: mysql, database, union, mariadb

Good day,

i have problem with "simple" query. When i execute it in different server i got other result set as what i need..

I tried to re-import all "tables" via export->import and still it's not working.

Where can be problem? Can be problem in MariaDB?

Database versions:

- 5.6.27 - **MySQL Community Server** (GPL), client: libmysql 5.0.11-dev
- 10.0.25-**MariaDB**-0+deb8u1 - (Debian), client: libmysql 5.5.49

Both running on **MyISAM** engine.

**Query:**

```
SELECT id, datum, ordinary FROM (SELECT *, 0 as `ordinary` FROM 
    `user_todolist` WHERE `done` = '0' 
    AND `deleted` = '0' AND `id_uzivatel` = '1' ORDER BY `datum` ASC) AS a1 
UNION 
SELECT id, datum, ordinary FROM (SELECT *, 1 as `ordinary` FROM 
    `user_todolist` WHERE `done` = '1' AND `deleted` = '0' AND 
    `id_uzivatel` = '1' ORDER BY `datum` DESC) AS a2 
ORDER BY `ordinary`
```

**Results (Left EXPECTED, Right Invalid):**

[image]

**SQL Explain(Top for Expected, Bot Invalid)**

[image]

Comment: Why is `ORDER BY datum ASC` then `ORDER BY datum DESC`? Try applying all the `Order By` conditions to the two select statements individually, rather than the overall union select.

Comment: It's ordering "tasks" - first part is ordered from "nearest" and second part is closed tasks what is needed to be sorted from "newest". I tryed to do it by one OrderBy - but in ideal i need only one question - but both ordering is in the same column. Final result set is shown in one paginated table in this required order.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY` is not necessarily a stable sort. When you apply `ORDER BY` to the result of the `UNION`, it can reorder  within the groups.

You don't need `ORDER BY ordinary` in the outer query. When you use `UNION`, the results are ordinarily in the order of the sub-queries, so the results of the first `SELECT` will come first, and the second `SELECT` after that.

You should change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`, though. By default, it's `UNION DISTINCT`, which means it has to combine the results of the queries to remove duplicates. Since there can never be duplicates between the queries (since they have different `ordinary` columns) this is unnecessary.

Another solution that doesn't rely on this (I'm not actually sure if it's guaranteed) is to take `ORDER BY datum` out of the subqueries, and make the main query use:

```
ORDER by ordinary, IF(ordinary = 0, datum, '') ASC, IF(ordinary = 1, datum, '') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

- ANSI standard says that the `ORDER BY` in a subquery can be ignored.  This is equivalent to saying that a table has no intrinsic order to the rows.
- *Recently* both Oracle and MariaDB (apparently independently) started taking advantage of this standard.
- `UNION ALL` is appropriate since there is no overlap of values, and since it is faster than `UNION DISTINCT`, due to the absence of a de-dup pass.
- `UNION` has *traditionally* been implemented by creating a temp table, feeding rows from one select into it, then the next select.
- *Recently* the need for the temp table was eliminated *in certain situations*.  This is a nice optimization.
- In the *future*, I expect multiple threads to perform the `SELECTs` in parallel.  This will *really* invalidate any assumptions you may enjoy today about how things or ordered.

Bottom line:  Remove the internal `ORDER BYs` and add an external `ORDER BY`, such as @Barmar's suggestion.

That way, your query will work 'correctly' in all past, current, and future versions of MySQL/MariaDB.  (I was first burned by the issue several years ago: [*Here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/).)

Meanwhile, switch to InnoDB, before it is totally removed.